# Azure error when sign in with different user

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure

I'm getting error when I sign-In second time in same browser tab.

Scenario,

1) Sign-In to Azure
2) Sign-Out from Azure

This is my sign out method.

[image]

again it's direct to same 1st login page.

I'm getting this error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The common cause of that is WebDAV. The old and good way to disable that would be to add to your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
     <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
  </modules>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="WebDAV" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I put that code to my site config and it's not fixed.. then I put it in to default site config also. But same error..

Comment: @isankathalagala may you share the project you are trying to run or the tutorial (if any) you followed? We lack the repro steps here... i will be happy to help, but the issue is too broad yet.